# Faulty scrollbars in builtin Delphi components

Tags: delphi, vcl, vcl-styles

In my Delphi 10.2 VCL application there seems to be a problem with the default modern `Windows10` VCL style. On builtin Delphi component, like the `TFontDialog`, the user cannot use vertical scrolling in dropdown components. The arrows can't be clicked and the scrollbar can't be dragged, only scrolling up and down with the mousewheel works. If I'm using older VCL styles (for example the old XP style `Windows`) this is not an issue, the user can use all controls and everything works as expected.

### TFontDialog Example

```
TFontDialog.Create(Form1);
TFontDialog.Execute;
```

[image: faulty scrollbars in a fontdialog]

Vertical scrolling in the color dropdown component is not usable (highlighted in red), only mouse scrolling is possible, the user cannot click the arrows or drag the scrollbar.

### TOpenPictureDialog Example

```
TOpenPictureDialog.Create(Form1);
TOpenPictureDialog.Execute;
```

[image: faulty scrollbars in a picturedialog]

Vertical scrolling in the dropdown component is not usable (highlighted in red).

### BrowseForFolder Example

```
TDirectoryListBox.directory := BrowseForFolder('Choose a folder', '', false);
```

[image: faulty scrollbars in browseforfolder]

Vertical scrolling in the color dropdown component is not usable (highlighted in red), only mouse scrolling is possible, the user cannot click the arrows or drag the scrollbar.

I tried the suggestion from @RRUZ in response to a different problem ([Delphi 10 Seattle - Vista Dialogs bug with VCL Styles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39042169/9529323)) to add the [VCL Styles Utils](https://github.com/RRUZ/vcl-styles-utils) project files, but I couldn't detect any changes with  the additional files in my uses section.

**edit**: Delphi 10.2 Version 25.0.29899.2631

Comment: Can't reproduce in 10.2.2. A great workaround would be not to use VCL styles, though.

Comment: Unfortunately the application allows users to switch styles, but I'll try to disable the VCL Styles of the components in question

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't fix the problem, but is acceptable to me as a workaround. @AndreasRejbrand suggested in his comment, that I do not use VCL Styles. I can't do that, but I got the idea from him to disable the styling of the components in question.

@RRUZ described in [How to disable vcl styles on external dll forms in delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42582696/9529323) how to null `TStyleManager.SystemHooks` and @AriochThe described in [Delphi. How to disable Vcl Themes for TFileOpenDialog and TOpenDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41669142/9529323) how to null `TStyleManager.SystemHooks` for a specific component. Which led me to the following workaround in `TForm1.FormCreate`:

```pascal
with TStyleManager do
    SystemHooks := SystemHooks - [shDialogs];
```

`TFontDialog` doesn't look much different (except for the down arrow), but the vertical scrollbar is fully functional now.

[image: working vertical scrollbar]